# Unable to remove a class from a div on small screens using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to remove a class from a few divs on small screens but unfortunately no success. Is there anything wrong with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
        $('body').removeClass('heightFull');
        $('#v-pills-step8').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrong selector  - you may mean `$('div').removeClass('heightFull');`. Also you want to check your doctype: `<!doctype html>`

Comment: There is nothing syntactically wrong with your code, but we don't know if it is correct for your page because you haven't shown us the HTML it applies to :) Are you *sure* it is the body tag you want?

Comment: @FluffyKitten `remove a class from a few divs`

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I was trying to prompt them into applying a bit of thought to it themselves :) (And pointing out there's a difference between syntactically wrong and logically wrong)

Comment: @Bloom a better solution might be to use css `@media` queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the body element. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
        $('div').removeClass('heightFull');
        $('#v-pills-step8').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to indicate the screen value in quotation marks, like this `'1025'`. this works for me. but I would suggest doing it with `media` queries.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < '1025') {
            $('body').removeClass('heightFull');
            $('#v-pills-step8').hide();
        }
});
```